# Managing "Final Destination" (death) mandates by the game

Tags: nethack

I've been playing a lot of nethack lately, and I'm still a beginner, but I've noticed that when you put yourself in a disadvantage, the game sees this and IT decides that you are going to die. Perhaps you are hungry - suddenly, monsters! Perhaps you are trying to stash items / clean levels or otherwise hauling something heavy - suddenly, an army! Or, maybe the game's just had enough of you and you open a door and there are two angry unicorns, a giant, and an angry djinn that just appeared out of nowhere and for no reason as a low-level character.

I know there is a lot written about what to do when you find yourself in a pickle, and I know that there are written Bad Ideas. But I just wanted to hear about this kind of situation. What exactly is going on?

I'm not a micromanager and I find it difficult to eat the exact turn my character becomes hungry, cure diseases exactly when they come on, etc, etc. And I know this is a hard game, but it seems as if whenever you find yourself in a bad spot, the game knows this and spawns monsters/situations that make things horribly, horribly worse. Is this some mechanic of in-game Luck, maybe?

Comment: It's likely that this is nothing more than confirmation bias. You remember this kind of death more than the kind where you just went down too fast and ran into high-level monsters or the kind where you just starve *because* it seems more unfair. Plus, you may notice that you're hungry because there are monsters, and you probably see more monsters when carrying something heavy because that makes you slow, which gives more time for monsters to spawn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this is most likely simple confirmation bias. You probably feel like you experience these kinds of deaths more because they feel unfair.

First, I would suggest installing the [statuscolors patch](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Statuscolors) if you don't already have it. The suggested options will show different colors for low health, hunger, and how burdened you are, which makes those easier to keep track of at a glance, and it especially helps you notice *transitions* to low health, hunger, or illness, so that you can deal with it immediately.

Second, if you're carrying something heavy and you encounter monsters, the first thing you should do is drop the heavy thing. It will still be there when you're done, and the speed gain will make up for the time it took to drop it in a couple of turns.

Third, encountering naturally spawning angry unicorns or djinn is very much abnormal. This may indicate the presence of a [bones level](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Bones), where a previous character died to those monsters (this is why I don't play with bones enabled). Or it might indicate that you're wearing a ring of conflict, which you probably don't want to be wearing early on. But most importantly, remember that you can run away, and live to fight another day. If you take either staircase, you leave the monsters behind (except a few that follow you if they're adjacent), and they'll stay put until you come back.

Answer (score 3):

As well as @murgatroid99's excellent answer, when your character is encumbered, it takes up more turns to move. The game does not slow down its spawning simply because the character has slowed. So to the player, it appears that monsters may be spawning at an alarmingly fast rate.

> Don't level up unnecessarily. With every level you gain the game will
>   throw harder monsters at you. No, this is not fair. Your equipment (AC
>   and so on) must improve in parallel, matching your level, otherwise
>   your opponents will eventually overwhelm you. Level up slowly by
>   letting your pet do much of the work. Kill primarily when threatened
>   or hungry. [[Why do I keep dying?]](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Why_do_I_keep_dying%3F)

I cannot speak for everyone but leveling up without good gear was one of my constant and biggest pitfalls, and the reason why monsters so far beyond my capabilities were being generated.